# Capture the Error returned within sql result data set using power shell script

Tags: sql, powershell

I am new to power shell and trying to execute multiple SQL scripts in a single PS script file. Below is my code,

```
Function ExecuteQuery($scriptname, $variableExe, $Databasename, $folder, $Optional)
{
invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile $ScriptLocation\$folder\$scriptname   -Variable $variableExe -database $Databasename 
-username $UsernameExecuteDBScript -password $PasswordExecuteDBScript -serverinstance $ServerName   -querytimeout 65535 
}
```

Then I am checking for any errors that may occur using the following code,

```
if($Error[0].Exception.Message -Match "Error") 
    {
    Write-Host '------------------------------------------------'
    Write-Host 'An Error has occured'
    Write-Host
    Write-Host $scriptname "execution Failed"
```

I am logging this SQL result, as well as the error messages generated in the command prompt using Start-Transcript

```
start-transcript $file

ExecuteQuery script1.SQL $null $dbname xy 0
ExecuteQuery script2.SQL $xyz $dbname xy 0  
ExecuteQuery script3.SQL $null $dbname xy 0
```

I execute my PS script using a .bat file.

But I have an issue with this, if any SQL query completed it's execution successfully , but the table returned has columns saying "Error 547, FK violation" or some other similar error messages, my powershell script or Start Transcript do not capture it. It just goes on and runs the script and next scripts in the list.

Below is a sample data returned by the sql execution. The query completes it's execution and goes on to the next script. But the actual execution of the delete did not happen due to the FK violation. Data is returned in the table with 3 columns

```
ERR_NUMBER  : 547
ERR_MESSAGE : The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK
          _abc_sample". The conflict occurred in database "sample", table "dbo.sample_LOOKUP", column 'CONFIG_ID'.
ERR_LINE    : 201
```

I want the Powershell script execution to be stopped/terminated and log the information into my log file when this happens.

Can anyone please help me out with this

Comment: have you tried `-erroraction stop`?

Comment: Yes I did, it didn't help unfortunately :(

Comment: ok now that i read it again.. you want to check the returned values (from a succeeded sql query) to see if their value is an error message? if you want that you have to inspect what you get back manually, if powershell stopped everytime you had a string with "error" in it the thing would blow up all over the place :D not sure if that is what you mean though, maybe you should clarify

Comment: Yes , you are right Paul. The SQL query is executed successfully and  so the powershell script goes on to execute the next query. But however, the result returned by the SQL query says the FK violation and hence couldn't perform delete. I would like to manually read the result set and check if it succeeded or failed, maybe search with error code 547 because thats the only error my script could generate potentially. But I am unable to read the output of SQL query because I use Start Transcript and it doesn't support storing results into a temp variable

Comment: you could try to use system.Data.SqlClient and see if that throws an error in your case, not sure but i think invoke-sqlcmd is not the best way to go for deletion, also what happens if you do something like $var = invoke-sqlcmd.... ? havent worked with sql in a long time so bare with me

Comment: You should be able to store a string with the error message using the [`-ErrorVariable` common parameter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847884.aspx).  You may also need `-OutputSqlErrors` or `AbortOnError`, which are specific to `Invoke-Sqlcmd`.  Beyond that, if `Invoke-SQLCmd` doesn't think an error has occurred, you might try specifying `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` at the beginning of your SQL query.